# Optimization of Church-encoded booleans in System F

Tags: lambda-calculus

I can encode booleans in pure lambda calculus like this:

```
type Bool = forall t. t -> t -> t  
true : Bool = \x y -> x
false : Bool = \x y -> y
```

Is there a procedure to optimize the following "dumb" function

```
dumb = \(b : Bool) -> b false false
```

to

```
dumb = \(b : Bool) -> false
```

I can imagine this is quite easy in Haskell with an ADT for example.

One way I can think of is counting the inhabitants of the type Bool (2) and then applying the function to both the inhabitants, discovering that the function will have the same result for any argument. This seems quite difficult to do in general though.

Comment: Are you familiar with Parametricity/[Free theorems](https://people.mpi-sws.org/~dreyer/tor/papers/wadler.pdf)? I'm 99% sure the free theorem for `forall t . t -> t -> t` would let you conclude that its only inhabitants are equivalent to `true` and `false` church-encoded. So you could then do an optimization where you evaluate both possible values and check if the results are equal. But I doubt this would scale past booleans. Church encodings are not known for their efficiency.

Comment: Yes that is what I meant with the last paragraph. I was wondering if there maybe was another way to optimize this case, that's why I asked the question.

Comment: Not an expert, but my impression is that if you care about optimizations then you shouldn't be using Church encodings. Maybe [Mendler encodings](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.02473) would have something more useful? But I'm not sure. Without the type discipline, you definitely can't make that optimization, since there are non-boolean functions that could be passed in.

Comment: Thanks for the link, that's very interesting! Yeah good point about types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without further assumptions you cannot perform the optimization because it is unsound in general. For example, we could interpret System F in a model that has fixed point operators, in which case there will be elements of `Bool` that are different from `false` and `true` (namely "undefined" `⊥`). In such a model, `dumb` will not be equal to `\ b . false` because `dumb ⊥ = ⊥` but `(\b . false) ⊥ = false`.

In your question you assumed that we know what it means to "optimize" a function. If we leave aside questions about efficiency, we still have to answer the question what it means for two closed terms in System F to be equal. There are several possibilities:

- closed terms $M$ and $N$ are equal if they reduce to the same normal form,
- closed terms $M$ and $N$ are equal if they are equal in some preferred model,
- closed terms $M$ and $N$ are equal if they are [observationally equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observational_equivalence),
- closed terms $M$ and $N$ are equal if they are extensionally equivalent (they give extensionally equivalent results when applied to extensionally equivalent arguments).

Parametricity, which was mentioned in the comments, may be helpful with some of the above. But it's difficult to discuss "optimization" until we know what counts as "equal", or else we cannot tell which optimizations are valid.